# Convert existing JavaScript object string property to an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious if it is possible to check if the object value exists and if it exists I want to check if it is a string or an `array`.

```
// var n is a dynamic variable that is retrieved from $(this)
var d = {};
if(typeof(d[n]) == "undefined"){
   d[n] = "value";

}else{
   if(typeof(d[n]) == "string"){
     //Convert string to array using its curent value plus an additional value

   }else{
     //Append value to array

   }
}
```

Currently I am using a loop to create an `object` for AJAX. I have a few of the same names for the data points similar to an input with the `name="name[]"`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `typeof` needs no parenthesis.

Comment: What is not working? Or are you asking for the comments to be written in code?

Comment: `d[n] = [d[n], "additional value"]`? You should provide inputs and expected outputs if you want a real answer. Also, you know jQuery has `$.serializeArray()`, right?

Comment: `d[n] = [].concat(d[n],v)` sames results if v is string or array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is reassign the property to an array if a string (`d[n] = [d[n], newValue]`), or call [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) if it's not.

```
var newValue = "testing123";

var d = {};
if(typeof d[n] == "undefined"){
    d[n] = "value";

}else{
    if(typeof d[n] == "string"){
        //Convert string to array using its current value plus an additional value
        d[n] = [d[n], newValue];
    }else{
        //Append value to array
        d[n].push(newValue);
    }
}
```